# what is the "col" value in visual studio text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In the bottom of the visual studio text editor it shows "Ln X Col Y". Line seems pretty self-explanatory and works predictably, but I'm a bit baffled about "Col" :-)

If there are Chinese characters in the line, moving the cursor to to the right (i.e. by one character) sometimes seems to advance the "Col" by 1 and sometimes by 2, even thought they are all multi-byte characters. what is it actually counting?

a subsidiary question so this is: Is there a simple way to find out the number of characters on a line?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The difference between column and character positions is evident for characters such as the tab character that can incorporate more than one column.

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.setlinecolchar.aspx).

Comment: It's not quite the right answer but along the right lines. I didn't use tabs but realised the Chinese characters are in a bigger font so they take up more than one "character". pretty strange for a fixed-width font but at least it explains it.

The weird thing is that didn't notice the 'ch' value on the screen which was of course exactly what I was looking for all along. I would almost go so far as to swear it wasn't shown when I was looking before but can't reproduce that now.

Comment: Tab was just an example. `such as the tab character`

Answer (score 2):

In visual studio, you can have ln X Col Y Ch Z. Sometimes you can have both unicode and ascii characters in your text editor and Col is used to find out how much space you need for that line.